# angular [$parse:ueoe] Unexpected end of expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am very new in Angular.. I tried to bind ng-init from the data that I get from ASP.NET codebehind..

The code looks like this:

```
<div class="ki-component" ng-app ng-init="init(<%= GetSmallCartData(3) %>)">
```

However I got an error "[$parse:ueoe] Unexpected end of expression". Here is more details

```
Error: [$parse:ueoe] Unexpected end of expression: init([{
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$parse/ueoe?p0=init(%5B%7B
    at angular.js:117
    at AST.peekToken (angular.js:15278)
    at AST.object (angular.js:15219)
    at AST.primary (angular.js:15137)
    at AST.unary (angular.js:15125)
    at AST.multiplicative (angular.js:15112)
    at AST.additive (angular.js:15103)
    at AST.relational (angular.js:15094)
    at AST.equality (angular.js:15085)
    at AST.logicalAND (angular.js:15077) "<div class="ki-component ng-scope" ng-app="smallBasket" ng-controller="smallBasketCtrl" ng-init="init([{" _customermaterialnumber":null,"_internallistprizetotal":null,"_prizediscount":null,"_prizeperunit":null,"itemid":null,"mdmaterialnumber":null,"customermaterialnumber":null,"quantity":"1","quantityasked":null,"mddescription":"k="" 7="" premium="" full="" control="" plus="" home="" *eu","mdadditionaldescription":null,"freegood":null,"tdlistprice":null,"netprice":null,"grossprice":null,"requestdatebyuser":null,"deliverableonuserdate":false,"deliverydatebysystem":null,"orderitemschedules":null,"picture":"https:="" d6mbshfzr0ulu.cloudfront.net="" pro="" ad2ede993af5d4cb1dc6da428e12bcc5.jpg","mdweightunit":null,"mdformatedarticleid":"1.317-133.0","mdean":null,"mddimensions":null,"mdpackagesize":null,"mdgrossweight":null,"mdpackageunit":null,"mdpalletsize":null,"mdclassification":null,"mdgrossweightunit":null,"mddangerousgood":false,"mdcompvolume":null,"mdcompvolumeunit":null,"mdvolume":null,"mdvolumeunit":null,"tdcurrencycode":null,"tdstock":null,"tdcountryoforigin":null,"tdhazardclassification":null,"tdunit":null,"conflict":false,"conflicttest":false,"newitem":false,"matchpalletsize":true,"recommendedcountforpallet":0,"shippingpoint":null,"enablearticlenr":false,"enablecustomermatnr":false,"palletquantity":null,"palletsize":null,"palletstackfactor":null}])"="">"
```

Can anyone help me why I got this error and how I should fix this?

Many Thanks

Comment: The data from your backend, is it a string? what is it? If it is then I'd suggest `ng-init="init('<%= GetSmallCardData(3) %>')"`.

Comment: Yes it is a string of an array object. I tried with ur suggestion but I got another error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unterminated quote at columns 5-8 ['[{] in expression [init('[{].